# java socket data processing

Tags: java, sockets, ethernet

I am currently working on a java program to get data from an internet device.

The connection and initialisation process is already working as expected, but when I want to process the data I received, something strange happens...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this error arises with the following code, when I want to print the received socket info:

```
static String tempstring;
        while((tempstring = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Client: " + tempstring);
        }

        System.out.print(tempstring);
```

The thing is, within the while loop the data is received correctly. But after that, in the last line print fucntion the data is not available anymore. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `static String tempstring;` cannot compile if located in a method. Please post the real code.

Comment: but your loop only terminates when `tempstring==null`, so of course it's null in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to print null value because you are assigning a line read from `reader` for every iteration and thus getting null when you exit the while loop. You need to concatenate every line you read in order to use it later.
Something like this will work:

```
String tempstring;  
String readerData = "";  
while((tempstring = reader.readLine()) != null){
        readerData += tempstring;
        System.out.println("Client: " + tempstring);
}
System.out.print(readerData);
```

Comment: did the job for me, thanks a lot! I now know what I did wrong! :) Thanks!